# jQuery, if span is empty remove containing p element

Tags: jquery

This is my markup;

```
<p class="slide-desc">
    <span>SOME TEXT</span>
</p>
```

What I want to do is remove the `<p class="slide-desc"></p>` completely if the `<span>` inside it is empty.

Is that possible?

I was using this before

```
$('.slide-desc:empty').remove();
```

But then I had to add the `span` so it no longer works as there is content contained within the `p` elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('.slide-desc > span:empty').parent().remove();
```

Note that this assumes the `span` is always the direct child of the `.slide-desc` element. If it's not, use this instead:

```
$('.slide-desc span:empty').closest('.slide-desc').remove();
```

Answer (score 3):

try this:

```
$('.slide-desc span:empty').closest('.slide-desc').remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try

```
$('.slide-desc').has('span:empty').remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this might be faster:

```
$('p.slide-desc').find("span:empty").parent("p.slide-desc").remove();
```